# I want to implement the automatic capture function that shows the game view in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using this as a capture.

```
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot($"Screenshot{_shotIndex}.png", size);
```

But the CpatureScreenshot() is too slow.

So I tried different scripts but failed. One of them is that I succeeded in capturing the **scene view**.

```
public void TakeTransparentScreenshot(Camera cam, int width, int height, string savePath)
    {
        // Depending on your render pipeline, this may not work.
        var bak_cam_targetTexture = cam.targetTexture;
        var bak_cam_clearFlags = cam.clearFlags;
        var bak_RenderTexture_active = RenderTexture.active;

        var tex_transparent = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        // Must use 24-bit depth buffer to be able to fill background.
        var render_texture = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(width, height, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
        var grab_area = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

        RenderTexture.active = render_texture;
        cam.targetTexture = render_texture;
        cam.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.SolidColor;

        // Simple: use a clear background
        cam.backgroundColor = Color.clear;
        cam.Render();
        tex_transparent.ReadPixels(grab_area, 0, 0);
        tex_transparent.Apply();

        // Encode the resulting output texture to a byte array then write to the file
        byte[] pngShot = ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG(tex_transparent);
        File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, pngShot);

        cam.clearFlags = bak_cam_clearFlags;
        cam.targetTexture = bak_cam_targetTexture;
        RenderTexture.active = bak_RenderTexture_active;
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(render_texture);
        Texture2D.Destroy(tex_transparent);
    }
```

[How do I capture a screenshot in Unity3d with a transparent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080597/how-do-i-capture-a-screenshot-in-unity3d-with-a-transparent-background/64552656)

I need to capture the **game view**, but this script does the scene view.

Inevitably I tried to implement a feature that was **automatically captured** using CaptureScreenshot() and Coroutine. it was too slow to work.

Comment: The script you posted doesn't capture the scene view ..  it depends on what camera you pass in and where you call it from ... You can improve it though by not everytime create and destroy a new render texture but rather reuse it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I solved the problem with your reply :)